# Function accepting a reference to std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I'm trying to pass values to a function accepting a `std::variant`.
I noticed I can use a function accepting a const reference to a variant value, but not a reference alone. Consider this code

```
#include <variant>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{ std::string msg{"foo"}; };
struct Bar{ std::string msg{"bar"}; };

using FooBar = std::variant<Foo,Bar>;

void f1(const FooBar&)
{
    std::cout << "yay" << std::endl;
}

void f2(FooBar&)
{
    std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
 
    f1(f); // fine
    f1(b); // fine 
    f2(f); // compile error
}
```

gives me error

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'FooBar&' {aka 'std::variant<Foo, Bar>&'} from expression of type 'Foo'
   42 |     f2(f);
```

so the first question is: *why is that prohibited?*
I can't figure out.

**Why I'm doing this?**
I'm trying to use two accessor function to read and modify the values using `std::visit`, something like this:

```
#include <variant>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{ std::string msg{"foo"}; };
struct Bar{ std::string msg{"bar"}; };

using FooBar = std::variant<Foo,Bar>;
   
std::string f3(const FooBar& fb)
{
    return std::visit([](auto& foobar){
        std::string ret = "yay ";
        return ret + foobar.msg;
    }, fb);
}

void f4(FooBar& fb)
{
    std::visit([](auto& foobar){
        foobar.msg += "doo";
    }, fb);
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;

    std:: cout << f3(f) << " " << f3(b); // fine
    f4(f); // does not compile
}
```

which of course does not compile with

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'FooBar&' {aka 'std::variant<Foo, Bar>&'} to an rvalue of type 'FooBar' {aka 'std::variant<Foo, Bar>'}
   44 |     f4(f);
      |        ^
```

So second question: *how can I achieve this behaviour?*

Comment: `f` is NOT a `FooBar`, but you can create a (temporary) `FooBar` from it. and temporary can't bind to non-const lvalue reference. (if it would compile, you won't modify `f`, but the temporary).

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first, and I wasnt the only one and then one thing led to another and it was a mess. I hope the new answer helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a temporary resulting from converting the `Foo` to a `std::variant<Foo,Bar>` to `f2`. C++ disallows this because binding a temporary to a non-const reference is most likely a bug. If it was possible you'd have no way to inspect the modified value anyhow.

You can workaround this by using a `std::variant` of references (actually `std::reference_wrapper`) and pass that by value. You'd then use two overloads, one for non-const and one for const references, in both cases the temporary `std::variant` can be passed by value while modifications inside the function are made directly on the object used to construct the `std::variant`:

```
#include <variant>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo{ std::string msg{"foo"}; };
struct Bar{ std::string msg{"bar"}; };

using FooBar = std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<Foo>,std::reference_wrapper<Bar>>;
using ConstFoobar = std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<const Foo>,std::reference_wrapper<const Bar>>;

void f1(ConstFoobar)
{
    std::cout << "yay" << std::endl;
}

void f2(FooBar)
{
    std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
 
    f1(f); // yay
    f1(b); // yay 
    f2(f); // wow
}
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/v5n9qzadq)

PS: The simpler solution is of course to have two overloads taking plain `Foo` and `Bar` (ie for each a non and a const reference overload, makes 4 in total). Though I suppose you are using `std::variant` for some other reasons not directly apparent from the example code.

Comment: Yes I'm using a function accepting a variant to not to write a gigaton of overload which do basically the same thing since the interface used is common but not polimorphic

Answer (score 2):

> So second question: how can I achieve this behaviour?

It seems you use `std::variant` to restrict possible argument.

If that is the case, template might be an alternative solution:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool isFooBar = std::is_same_v<T, Foo> || std::is_same_v<T, Bar>;

template <typename FooBar, std::enable_if_t<isFooBar<FooBar>, int> = 0>
void f1(const FooBar&)
{
    std::cout << "yay" << std::endl;
}

template <typename FooBar, std::enable_if_t<isFooBar<FooBar>, int> = 0>
void f2(FooBar&)
{
    std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
}

template <typename FooBar, std::enable_if_t<isFooBar<FooBar>, int> = 0>
std::string f3(const FooBar& fb)
{
    std::string ret = "yay ";
    return ret + fb.msg;
}

template <typename FooBar, std::enable_if_t<isFooBar<FooBar>, int> = 0>
void f4(FooBar& fb)
{
    fb.msg += "doo";
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
 
    f1(f); // yay
    f1(b); // yay
    f2(f); // wow

    std:: cout << f3(f) << " " << f3(b) << std::endl; // yay foo yay bar
    f4(f); // f.msg = foodoo
    std::cout << f.msg<< std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GrsE8TMYn)